# What ways are acceptable to ask about the time (clock)?

Tags: phrase-choice

What ways are acceptable to ask about the times (clock)? 
I know two or three ways such as: "what is the time?" or "what time is it?" + "What time is it **now?**", "what is the time **now**?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow Paz said:

> The most common way to ask is: **What time is it?**

I think that indeed the most common way I would ask a friend, coworker, or family member.

Simon Nicholls suggested:

> **Do you have the time?
>
>    Could I have the time?**

I think those are the most common ways I would ask a stranger for the time:

> *Excuse me, do you happen to have the time?*

Finally, you asked about:

> **What time is it now?**

I would say your wording there is grammatical, but the *now* at the end is unnecessary, and that, overall, it would sound more natural and idiomatic if you omitted the word "now." When asking about the time, the default meaning is the current time, unless you somehow specify that you're asking about another time. For example:

> What time does the play start tomorrow?
>   What time did you finally go to sleep last night?

Comment: I think the way for asking questions should be with "please" in the end. "Could I have the time please?"

Comment: @Arch - There’s nothing wrong with that, of course, but I think you can still be polite even without the “please” at the end. In this case, I think that saying “Excuse me...” with the right intonation is another way to be formal and polite.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have the time?
>   Could I have the time?

That's about it. Most regular phrases are do you have the time and what time is it in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to ask is:

What time is it?